# Android market does not find application on some devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I added the application into Android market, but some phones(i think with android lower than Froyo(2.2)) does not find it!

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.skkap.utimetable"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".timetable"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Preferences" android:name="Preferences" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".edit_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".add_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".move_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity> 
        <activity android:name=".copy_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity> 
        <activity android:name=".export_to_calendar_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".export_to_csv_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".import_from_tpu_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>        
        <activity android:name=".import_from_csv_dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>    
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8"></uses-sdk>
<supports-screens
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
</manifest>
```

If you can try in on your android - app.name: uTimetable

What I have to do for fix it?

Comment: Just a guess: Take out the `<supports-screens>` element entirely. You don't need it, and without it, the market will just assume it works on all screens.

Comment: I tried it before. I added <supports-screens> tag for sure, after i found a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @skkap mentioned in the comments, and I discovered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761354/application-not-installable-on-motorola-xoom-from-android-marketplace) try to turn off copy protection on your application and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Were you testing on a device running 1.5 (which is lower than your minSdkVersion)?  I just tested on a device running 2.1 and one running 2.2.1, and it showed up on both.

Comment: I thing my problem in copy protection now.