# Application not installable on Motorola Xoom from Android Marketplace

Tags: android, google-play, xoom

My Android application is not installable on a Motorola Xoom from the Android Marketplace. I've already followed the instructions available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116768/application-does-not-show-up-in-android-market-for-motorola-xoom-tablet), to no avail. Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.foo.app"
      android:versionCode="7"
      android:versionName="7.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".FooActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />  

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />  

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm betting dollars to donuts it's your permissions that have to do with phone functionality, like READ_PHONE_STATE. Set those to `android:required="false"` too and see what happens.

Comment: Is it the same format to set your uses-permission's to false as it is for uses-feature's. For example, should I just do: <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" /> ?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, I had to turn off copy protection.

Answer (score 0):

So a potential workaround is to set the `android:minSdkVersionto="4"` and just remove the `supports-screens` all together.

Comment: I've already tried removing supports-screens altogether, and it didn't help. Why would setting the minSdkVersion to 4 help in this case?